# How to pass parameters with space to controller from URL in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have one method in controller that receive several parameters:

```
public function api(){
  $url_params = $this->uri->segment_array();

   //...
}
```

and this is example of URL:

```
http://testsite.com/services/api/invite-businesses/contact_name/_testing/message/some%20message/url/some_URL/
```

So my array seems like:

```
array(10) {
  [1]=>
  string(8) "services"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "api"
  [3]=>
  string(17) "invite-businesses"
  [4]=>
  string(12) "contact_name"
  [5]=>
  string(12) "_testing"
  [6]=>
  string(7) "message"
  [7]=>
  string(14) "some%20message"
  [8]=>
  string(3) "url"
  [9]=>
  string(4) "some_URL"
}
```

You can see that one of parameters has space: `some%20message`.

But I want to get real value, a.e. `some message`. The value might contain any other character that URL converts to `%xx`.

How to get real value

Comment: Look for function `urldecode()` and `urlencode()`

Comment: Thank you mate, I got 2 answers, anyways you was 1st so glad to upvode and accept your answer

Comment: curious, you use this for an **API** but why not have a couple elements as in URL and others in POST? Would eliminate things like your `message` having spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**urldecode()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to decode string

```
...
 $url_params = $this->uri->segment_array();
 foreach($url_params as &$param) {
   $param = urldecode($param);
 }
 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try [urldecode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).

```
echo urldecode("some%20message");
```

This will return "some message"

Answer (score 1):

Use [**urldecode()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to Decode URL-encoded string